# Swapping every pair of items in an F# list

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequences

I'm positive that there is a better way to swap items in a list by pairs ( [1;2;3;4] -> [2;1;4;3] ) as I'm doing too many appends for my liking but I'm not sure how best to do it.

```
let swapItems lst =
    let f acc item =
        match acc with
        | [] -> [item]
        | hd :: next :: tl when tl <> [] -> [next] @ tl @ [item;hd]
        | _ -> item :: acc
    List.fold f [] lst
```

How can I improve this? This only works on lists that have an even length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
let rec swapItems = function
    | []
    | _::[] as l -> l
    | a::b::t ->
        b::a::(swapItems t)
```

?

Comment: I think doing it this way is slightly more elegant `function |a::b::t -> b::a::t |a -> failwith "not enough elements"`

Comment: brillant thanks, and curses to F# for always making things so simple ;)

Comment: @jpalmer, I don't know why he is doing this, but I presumed he also wanted this solution to work for lists of odd number of elements.

Comment: @Ramon - I didn't realise that he also reorderd `4,3` as well - my solution doesn't work, although you can still combine the first two cases in your function if you move them to the end

Comment: @jpalmer, yes, it is a matter of style. I try to refrain from using a final-clause match cases.

Comment: You can shorten it if you make the last case first: `let rec swapItems = function a::b::t -> b::a::(swapItems t) | l -> l`

Comment: @Daniel, that's what jpalmer suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read his comment closely enough. I saw `failwith` and assumed it's different. I guess that remains one slight difference from his.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest possible solution:

```
let rec swapItems = function
  | a::b::xs -> b::a::swapItems xs
  | xs -> xs
```

I like to make the names of variables that are sequences like lists "plural", e.g. `xs` instead of `x`.

Note that this is not tail recursive so it will stack overflow if you give it a very long list.

Answer (score 1):

Using higher order functions this can be done as:

```
let swapItems l =
    l |> List.toSeq |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a,b) -> if i % 2 = 0 then seq [b;a] else Seq.empty)
    |> Seq.concat |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: A list is a seq, you don't have to call ``List.toSeq``. I'm not sure it even does something (more than forcing the type-checker).